# Trying to delete a specific list from a different file in python?

Tags: python, easygui

```
from re import I
from easygui import *
import reservationhold
list = []
reserv_made = []
choices2 = ["Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday"]

times1 = ["09:00 - 10:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00",
          "11:00 - 12:00",
          "12:00 - 13:00",
          "13:00 - 14:00",
          "14:00 - 15:00",
          "15:00 - 16:00",
          "16:00 - 17:00"]
times2 = ["09:00 - 10:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00",
          "11:00 - 12:00",
          "12:00 - 13:00",
          "13:00 - 14:00",
          "14:00 - 15:00", 
          "15:00 - 16:00",
          "16:00 - 17:00"]
times3 = ["09:00 - 10:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00",
          "11:00 - 12:00",
          "12:00 - 13:00",
          "13:00 - 14:00",
          "14:00 - 15:00",
          "15:00 - 16:00",
          "16:00 - 17:00"]
text = "Hello! What would you like to do today?"
title = "Main Screen"
option1 = ["Make A Reservation", "Cancel A Reservation", "See Reservations"]
choice = choicebox(text,title,option1)
if choice == option1[0]:
    text = "Which Conference Room would you like to make a reservation for? Please select one of the following options:"
    title = "Conference room reservation"
    choices1 = ["Conference Room 1", "Conference Room 2", "Conference Room 3"]
    choice = choicebox(text, title, choices1)
    list += ({choice})

#-----Conference room 1-----#
    if choice == choices1[0]:
        text = "Which day you like to reserve the conference room for?"
        title = "Conference room reservation"
        message = "Selected items : " + str(choice)

        day1 = choicebox(message, text, choices2)
        list += ({day1})

        day1 == choices2[1]
        text = "What time you want to reserve the room for?"
        title = "Time selection"
        time1 = choicebox(text, title, times1)
        list += ({time1})
        with open('reservationhold.py','a') as f:
            f.write(f"{list}" + "\n")

elif choice == option1[1]:
        room = "Conference Room 1"
        reserv_made += ({room})
        day = "Monday"
        reserv_made += ({day})
        time = "09:00 - 10:00"
        reserv_made += ({time})
        print(reserv_made)
        with open("reservationhold.py", "r+") as f:
            data = f.readlines()
        with open("reservationhold.py", "w") as f:   
            for line in data:
                if line.strip("\n") == reserv_made:
                    f.write(data)
        # f.seek(0)
        # for i in data:    
        #     if i == reserv_made :
        #         f.write(i)
```

Hi everyone! I am fairly new to python and wanted to ask a question. I'm trying to make a reservation system in python with easygui as graphical interface. What this program does is make a reservation and stores it in a different python file that is named reservationhold. I am trying to make a cancel service that removes that specific line from the reservationhold file but it deletes everything in the file with the code that i have. I just want to remove a specific line from the other file and not everything. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: ```new_data = [new_line for new_line in data if reserv_made not in new_line] ; f.writelines(new_data)``` under your ```with open()``` line, should be what you need.  This will add back every line that does not have ```reserv_made``` in it.

Comment: I get the error 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list when performing the cancellation for the reservation

Comment: ```new_data = [new_line for new_line in data if str(reserv_made) not in new_line] ; f.writelines(new_data)```  <-- try that.